# Filter by user or his group in dynamics crm SQL-based report

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

I have created a SQL-based report in Dynamics CRM 365. Filter by date works fine, but I can't make it filter by owning user and his groups. My users want to be able to see they activities by they department.
Here is the query:

```sql
select  distinct (CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activityid), CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.ownerid as ownerid, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.owneridname as name, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecodename as activityType, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.scheduledstart as start, 
        CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.scheduledend as finish, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.regardingobjectidname as client, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.subject as subject, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.description as description,
        dbo.GetKR_Sales_Chanel_Value(app.kr_sales_chanel,CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode) as kr_sales_chanel, app.kr_result as kr_result, 
        dbo.kr_ActivityMembers(CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activityid, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode) as participants
from    FilteredActivityPointer as CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer
left outer join     FilteredAppointment as app
on      CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activityid=app.activityid
left outer join FilteredEmail as em 
on      CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activityid=em.ActivityId
where   CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode=4212 or CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode=4201 or CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode=4202 or CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode=4210 
order by kr_sales_chanel desc, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.owneridname, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecodename asc, CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.scheduledend asc
```

We have configured departments and manager hierarchy. Can you give me any directions?

Comment: Can you show us example of the current output and desired output?

Comment: Current output return activities only for current user but no records of his 
colleagues. I want to show all records in department for all users in this department.

Comment: Can a user see his colleagues activities using advanced find?
If not, that would explain why they can't see them in the reports either.
I suspect that Read.Activity permission is set to 'User' (ie, small pie setting).

Comment: @MikeFeingold, no. It's set to business unit. And it works in Advanced Find.

Comment: What results do you get if running your query against the database (eg, using SQL Server Mgmt Studio) rather than from a report

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comment

> Current output return activities only for current user but no records of his colleagues. I want to show all records in department for all users in this department.

In your query there is no condition to filter by user. When I run the query without your specific functions (kr_), it shows me activities for all users. If you see only data for one user, there might one of those issues:

1. You don’t have right to see others records. Can you check it? Can you run it as Administrator?
2. You use `CRMAF_` prefiltering. How do you run the report? Do you input some filter? Do you run it from Activity View showing just your activities?

---

**EDIT 1**

Consider also some improvements:

1. join to email is not used.
2. Shorter condition:

```sql
where   
  CRMAF_FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecode IN (4212, 4201, 4202, 4210)
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Considering comment

> I'm using CRM Advanced Find feature for filters. There is 2 filters: 1. Time. 2. **Current user or his groups**. If I disable second filter, user see all records from all users.

In the latest version of CRM, there are these options (maybe called differently earlier):

1. `Equals Current User’s Teams` – related to the Teams (usualy project based teams; crossing company hierarchy and business units). The owner must be the team to see the records.
2. `Equals Current User or His Reporting Hierarchy` – seems like the condition you need (use for manager/reporting hierarchy of business units). You need to allow this model in Settings – Security – Hierarchy Security.

Comment: I'm using CRM Advanced Find feature for filters. There is 2 filters: 1. Time. 2. Current user or his groups. If I disable second filter, user see all records from all users. I'm running it as a report from Reports View in CRM.

Comment: Equals Current User or His Reporting Hierarchy – seems like the condition you need (use for manager/reporting hierarchy of business units). You need to allow this model in Settings – Security – Hierarchy Security.                                                                                                   I've tried this one. Still no effect. I will check my hierarchy once again. Thank you.

Comment: Does this condition work in Advanced Find, or as filter in any View? (I mean filtering using hierarchy)